# VB.NET FormatNumber equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is there a C# equivalent for the VB.NET `FormatNumber` function?

I.e.:

```
JSArrayString += "^" + (String)FormatNumber(inv.RRP * oCountry.ExchangeRate, 2);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In both C# and VB.NET you can use either the [.ToString()](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/UseToStringtoformatvalues.htm) function or the [String.Format()](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/UseStringFormattoformatavalue.htm) method to format the text.

Using the .ToString() method your example could be written as:

```
JSArrayString += "^" + (inv.RRP * oCountry.ExchangeRate).ToString("#0.00")
```

Alternatively using the String.Format() it could written as:

```
JSArrayString = String.Format("{0}^{1:#0.00}",JSArrayString,(inv.RRP * oCountry.ExchangeRate))
```

In both of the above cases I have used custom formatting for the currency with # representing an optional place holder and 0 representing a 0 or value if one exists.

Other formatting characters can be used to help with formatting such as D2 for 2 decimal places or C to display as currency. In this case you would not want to use the C formatter as this would have inserted the currency symbol and further separators which were not required.

See "[String.Format("{0}", "formatting string"};](http://idunno.org/archive/2004/14/01/122.aspx)" or "[String Format for Int](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-int/)" for more information and examples on how to use String.Format and the different formatting options.

Comment: For a full list of predefined number formatting options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

An alternative would be to use ToString("D2")

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the .ToString(string) methods.
For instance,

```
int number = 32;
string formatted = number.ToString("D4");
Console.WriteLine(formatted);
// Shows 0032
```

Note that in C# you don't use a number to specify a format, but you use a character or a sequence of characters.
Formatting numbers and dates in C# takes some minutes to learn, but once you understand the principle, you can quickly get anything you want from looking at the reference.

Here's a couple MSDN articles to get you started :

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
[Formatting Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxft59x.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatters to accomplish the same thing.

```
double MyNumber = inv.RRP * oCountry.ExchangeRate;
JSArrayString += "^" + MyNumber.ToString("#0.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

While I would recommend using ToString in this case, always keep in mind you can use ANY VB.Net function or class from C# just by referencing Microsoft.VisalBasic.dll.